# LINQ: How to convert a composite LINQ result to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to use LINQ to sort data that is going to be used into a report. The report strucuture looks like this:

---

### Developer name

Date | Hours | Project Name | Week Ending 
Date | Hours | Project Name | Week Ending 
Date | Hours | Project Name | Week Ending

### Developer name

Date | Hours | Project Name | Week Ending 
Date | Hours | Project Name | Week Ending

### Developer name

Date | Hours | Project Name | Week Ending 
Date | Hours | Project Name | Week Ending 
Date | Hours | Project Name | Week Ending

---

I am bringing all that data from a .dbml file. For such sorting i have this linq query:

```
DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<s_SummaryReportResult> res = context.s_timesheet_SummaryReport(startDate, endDate);

        var orb = from c in res
                  group c by c.developer
                  into devgroup
                  select new 
                  {   
                      Dev = devgroup.Key,
                      devData = from o in res
                                      select new {
                                        o.Date,
                                        o.Hours,
                                        o.projectname,
                                        o.week_ending
                                      }};

IDictionary dic_orb = orb.ToDictionary(result => result.Dev.ToString(), result => result.devData);


        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in dic_orb)
        {
          object brr =  item.Value;
        }
```

Sadly, on the foreach step i get an "InvalidCastException".

Any clues in how i can resolve that foreach, or in a sense, how to group better that LINQ query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dic_orb` is a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<'a>>` where `'a` is the anonymous type defined in your query. The type `KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<'a>>` is not convertible to `KeyValuePair<string, object>` hence the invalid cast. The fix is to declare `item` using var in your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var item in dic_orb)
{
    object brr =  item.Value;
}
```

Since `item.Value` is an `IEnumerable<'a>` you can iterate it using

```
var brr = item.Value;
foreach(var b in brr)
{
}
```

If you just want to iterate all nested collections you can use

```
foreach(var b in dic_orb.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Vaue))
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i still need to know how to iterate brr as it has several other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure result.devData is of type `object`?

Just change

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in dic_orb)
```

To

```
foreach (var item in dic_orb)
```

And you should get the right types automatically. Otherwise inspect what type `devData` is and change your KeyValuePair accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. That did fix the cast exception, but i still have problems trying to iterate that dictionary value. devData type is System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<ISUnified.Reports.s_timesheet_SummaryReportResult,<>f__AnonymousType1<System.DateTime,decimal,string,System.DateTime?>>